# Репозиторий «http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu serena Release» не содержит файла Release

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Когда я пытаюсь сделать `sudo apt-get update` у меня выходит такое:

> W: Репозиторий «linux.dropbox . com/ubuntu serena Release» не содержит файла Release.
>
> N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
>
> N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
>
> E: Не удалось получить linux.dropbox . com/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 54.192.98.213 80]
>
> E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.

Как это исправить?

При вводе в консоль команды `tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; lsb_release -a` вышло это:

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib main non-free'

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list <==
deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu serena main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list <==
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com serena main upstream import backport #id:linuxmint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ xenial partner

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-xenial.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-atom-xenial.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-wine-builds-xenial.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial main

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Release:    18.1
Codename:   serena
```

Comment: Вы не знаете что означает код 404 ? Это значит, что страница не найдена, т.е. данных там больше нет. Вы оттуда больше ничего не скачаете. Уберите этот источник из apt

Comment: Как это исправить. Недавно пересел на Linux

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод команды `tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; lsb_release -a`

Comment: скопируйте и вставьте, пожалуйста, **текст**. вся необходимая информация должна быть в тексте вопроса, а не на сторонних ресурсах (да ещё и, наверно, картинкой).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

несуществующий репозиторий `http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/selena` описан в вашей системе в файле `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`.

его лучше удалить:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```

остальные источники пакетов (даже «левые», с `ppa.launchpad.net`), выглядят работоспособными, поэтому (после удаления файла) обновление списка пакетов должно пройти нормально:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Кокнретно для `Linux Mint Serena` подойдёт такая строка:

Добавляем адрес репы:

```
echo deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu xenial main '#Dropbox' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dropbox.list
```

Добавляем gpg-ключ:

```
wget https://linux.dropbox.com/fedora/rpm-public-key.asc -O - | apt-key add -
```

Всё из-под суперпользователя.