# Репозиторий не содержит файла Release

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Версия ОС Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Поставил из deb файла приложение [pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/). Чтобы получать обновление для программы, по инструкции с сайта, добавил репозиторий:

```
curl -L https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-pomodoro.list"
```

На попытку получить данные о пакетах `apt-get update` отвечает:

```
W: Репозиторий «https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04  Release» не содержит файла Release.
N: Данные из этого репозитория нельзя аутентифицировать, и поэтому потенциально из небезопасно использовать.
N: Смотрите справочную страницу apt-secure(8) о создании репозитория и настройке пользователя.
E: Не удалось получить https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Packages  Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
E: Некоторые индексные файлы не скачались. Они были проигнорированы или вместо них были использованы старые версии.
```

При этом в логе все записи относящиеся к целевому репозиторию имеют вид:

```
Игн:10 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04  Translation-en
```

Смотрел похожие вопросы, ([например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627806/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9-http-linux-dropbox-com-ubuntu-serena-release-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-r)), но это решение мне не подходит судя по всему. По предлагаемой в том топике команде `tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; lsb_release -a` получаю следующее (комментарии удалил):

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list <==
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse


==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-pomodoro.list <==
deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/ /
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: там адрес неправильно указан. должен быть слэш перед именем репозитория: не `...home:kamilprusko...`, а `...home:/kamilprusko...`. см. [пример](https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Debian_builds#Configuring_sources.list). иначе сервер выдаёт лишний редирект, которому apt не следует. сравните вывод: `$ wget -O --spider 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Release'` и `$ wget -O --spider 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Release'`

Comment: а вообще пакет *gnome-shell-pomodoro* есть и в каком-то из по умолчанию подключаемых репозиториев в дистрибутиве *ubuntu 16.04*

Comment: спасибо огромное! А то я уже весь мозг сломал. Как можно пометить ваш комментарий как ответ?

Comment: отправил разрабу сообщение об ошибке, чтобы другие не мучались

Answer (score 3, accepted):

при обращении по указанному адресу сервер возвращает 301-й код — перенаправление на **правильный** адрес (у которого перед именем репозитория указан слэш):

```
$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Release'
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 15:42:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.34 (Linux/SUSE)
Location: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/kamilprusko/xUbuntu_16.04/Release
Content-Length: 381
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

именно так (`/kamilprusko`, а не `kamilprusko`) должен быть указан путь к репозиторию в *obs-e*.

см. пример в документации: https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Debian_builds#Configuring_sources.list

если в файл `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` внести такое исправление, то *apt* нормально получит всё, что запрашивает у сервера.

---

доп. информация: [apt does not handle HTTP redirects](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/18645).